# Метиз или метизов?

Tags: морфология

Мне пришлось писать специализированный текст о всевозможных крепежных деталях. В общем они называются "метизы" — "металлические изделия". Но как это слово склоняется? Вернее, меня интересует конкретно родительный падеж: "метиз" или "метизов"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Родительный множественного - метизов.

> метизы, -ов, ед. метиз, -а (металлоизделия)

(грамота)
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EC%E5%F2%E8%E7%FB